# Asserting a checkbox is not checked by default in WebDriver with Junit

Tags: checkbox, junit, webdriver, assert

I'm using WebDriver with Junit 4.11 and I want to assert that a checkbox is not selected by default, and to do that I'm unsure which constructor method to choose.

The following is from the DOM before the checkbox is selected:

```
<input type="checkbox" id="c234" name="instantAd" value="true" class="t-checkbox-A">
```

Then, once the checkbox becomes selected a 'checked' is added, like so:

```
<input type="checkbox" id="c234" name="instantAd" value="true" checked="" class="t-checkbox-A">
```

I have tried the following:

```
WebElement checkBox = chrome.findElement(By.cssSelector("input.t-checkbox-A[name=\"instantAd\"]"));

    new WebDriverWait(chrome, 5).until(ExpectedConditions.visibilityOfElementLocated(By.cssSelector("input.t-checkbox-A[name=\"instantAd\"]")));

    Assert.assertEquals("null",checkBox.getAttribute("checked"));

    checkBox.click();

    Assert.assertEquals("true",checkBox.getAttribute("checked"));
```

The first assertion fails. Perhaps this is because the 'checked' attribute isn't visible in the DOM yet, at a guess.

The stacktrace is displaying:

> java.lang.AssertionError: expected: java.lang.String but was: null

I've searched many different posts but none offer me the answer Im looking for, and when checking http://junit.sourceforge.net/javadoc/org/junit/Assert.html for info and guidance (as being new to test automation, Im finding it difficult to work out what I need in my constructor.

Any help would be most appreciated.

Comment: Try using the '.isSelected()` method instead. So verify via `assertTrue` rather than `assertEquals`. That's how we do it in Python, I imagine it would be similar in Java?

Answer (score 1):

There is a less preferable way to achieve the goal, than @mark suggested. (For cases when isSelected() does not work).

```
boolean isFound = false;
try {
  isFound = driver.findElement(By.cssSelector("input.t-checkbox-A[name=\"instantAd\"][checked]")).isDisplayed();
} catch (NoSuchElementException e) {
// Do nothing 
}
Assert.assertFalse(isFound);
checkBox.click();
try {
  isFound = driver.findElement(By.cssSelector("input.t-checkbox-A[name=\"instantAd\"][checked]")).isDisplayed();
} catch (NoSuchElementException e) {
// Do nothing 
}
Assert.assertTrue(isFound);
```

In short, the code tries to verify if the element with the "checked" attribute is displayed. If it is, then isFound is set to true, else isFound remains false

There are disadvantages:

- too much code
- the test will spend additional 5 seconds before throwing the NoSuchElementException when the element is not found

The "try" clause can be externalized to a separate method.

Comment: Thanks for your response @Vlad.Bachurin although the second assertion was failing when I ran the code. You're right about it being alot of code and taking a few more seconds to run if I used less code, so I may have found another way around it. I'll post it as an answer.

Answer (score 0):

With the help from @Francis on SQA Stackexchange I managed to solve the issue to assert a checkbox to be deselected by default.

The code that I had written (posted in my question above) contained the below assertion:

```
Assert.assertEquals("null",checkBox.getAttribute("checked"));
```

What I needed (again, thanks to Francis for suggesting this method) was the below assertNull:

```
Assert.assertNull(checkBox.getAttribute("checked"));
```

Job done.

Many thanks to all that looked into this.